# Grails Database Migration Load Data

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, database-migration

I have initialy created a changeset which loads(via loadData) countries into my database if its synced with my grails application. Now I already have a system which is running in productive mode and want to change the loaded initial data of countries.

For example there is now only 2 columns instead of 4 in countries because the others are not needed anymore. How can I handle this at best?

I already changed the original changeset but this was not a good idea as I am getting only errors now.

Update:
Sorry I didnt mentioned it in my post. I am already using the database migration plugin which is using liquibase.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever need to change your database, the correct process is to create a new migration, rather than try to change an old one.

If you created a migration to load the data with four columns, then you should create a migration to drop the extra columns down to two.    If the production database is differs from development (e.g. already has two columns), you can create a migration with failOnError=false to sync them.  Leave the migration that loads the data alone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use liquidbase - http://www.grails.org/plugin/liquibase

or write your own alter statement in sql to drop the columns that are not needed.

Hope that helps.